# proof of KerA = ImB implies ImA^T = KerB^T

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose some matrices $A\in\bf{R}^{n\times n}$ with ${\bf rank}(A)=r$ and $B\in {\bf R^{n\times (n-r)}} $ satisfies ${\bf Ker}(A) = {\bf Im}(B)$.

In this situation, I thought ${\bf Ker}B^{\bf T} = {\bf Im}A^{\bf T}$ is also true, but I couldn't make a proof.

Of cource, it is easy to show ${\bf Ker}B^{\bf T} \supseteq {\bf Im}A^{\bf T}$ but I didn't come up with the idea of the opposite side.

Could someone give me a proof or some hints? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Use dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** One approach is to note that $\operatorname{Im}(A^T) = \ker(A)^\perp$, where $V^\perp$ denotes the orthogonal complement of the subspace $V$.